# cluster features styling (by value return of the function)

Tags: openlayers-2

Whether it's possible to insert the return value of the function to the field of property?
I would like cluster features styling depends of average temperatures. My code:

```
    var highRule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.GREATER_THAN,
    property: "${val}", <---------THIS------------------------------------------>
    value: 15
}),
symbolizer: {
    fillColor: colors.high,
    fillOpacity: 0.9, 
    strokeColor: colors.s_high,
    strokeOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeWidth: 15,
    pointRadius: "${point_radius}",
    label: "${val}", //°C",
    labelAlign: "cm",       
    labelOutlineWidth: 0.5,
    fontColor: "#00376d",
    fontOpacity: 1,
    fontSize: "10px",
    fontWeight: "bold"
}

    });

    var style_temp = new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
rules: [singleRule, lowRule, middleRule, highRule],
context: {
            val: function(feature) {
                if(feature.cluster.length > 1) {
                    var sumValue = 0;
                    for (var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length;i++) 
                    {
                        sumValue += parseFloat(feature.cluster[i].attributes.tzewn);
                    }
                    var averageValue = (sumValue/feature.cluster.length).toFixed(1);
                    return averageValue+"\n°C  "; 
                                                } 
                else  
                    var Value = feature.cluster[0].attributes.tzewn;
                    return Value+"\n°C  ";
                                    },
            point_radius: function(feature) {
                if(feature.cluster.length > 1) 
                    return (feature.cluster.length/9) + 10; 
                else  return  8;
            }
    }}  );
```

This code doesn't work, so syntax ---> property: "${val}" <--- is not correct.

Comment: It's another way to set various color depends on average value of cluster features. In context block: new variable 'fill', which redundant calculates average cluster features and return proper 'fill' color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And problem solution:

```
    var style_temp = new OpenLayers.Style(
{
    fillColor: "${fill}", <-------additional variable------------>
    fillOpacity: 0.6, 
    strokeColor: "${fill}",<-------additional variable------------>
    strokeOpacity:1,
    strokeWidth: 4,
    pointRadius: "${point_radius}",
    label: "${val}\n°C",
    labelAlign: "cm",
    labelOutlineWidth: 0.5,
    fontColor: "#00006d",
    fontOpacity: 1,
    fontSize: "9px",
    fontWeight: "bold"
}, {
context: {

        val: function(feature) {

                if(feature.cluster.length > 1) {
                    var sumValue = 0;
                    var counter = 0;
                    for (var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length; i++) 
                    {
                        if (feature.cluster[i].attributes.tzewn)

                        {   sumValue += parseFloat(feature.cluster[i].attributes.tzewn);
                            counter += 1;
                        }

                    }
                    if (sumValue)
                    {
                        var averageValue = (sumValue/counter).toFixed(1);
                        return averageValue;
                    } else {
                        return "-";
                    }
                                                } 
                else  
                    if (feature.cluster[0].attributes.tzewn)
                    {var Value = feature.cluster[0].attributes.tzewn;
                    return Value;
                    }
                    else {return "-";};
                                    },
             <------------calculate aditional variable fill------------->
            fill: function(feature) {
                if(feature.cluster.length > 1) {
                    var sumValue = 0;
                    var counter = 0;
                    for (var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length; i++) 
                    {
                        if (feature.cluster[i].attributes.tzewn)

                        {   sumValue += parseFloat(feature.cluster[i].attributes.tzewn);
                            counter += 1;
                        }

                    }
                    var averageValue = (sumValue/counter).toFixed(1);
                    if (averageValue < 6)
                        {
                            return "#009cff"; //blue
                        }
                    else if (averageValue >= 6 && averageValue < 9)
                        {
                            return "#ec7d3f"; // orange
                        } 
                    else if (averageValue >= 9 )
                        {
                            return "#ff4a4a"; // red
                        } 
                    else { return "#8a8a8a"; }// grey                   
                    }
                else { 
                    var Value = 0;
                    Value = feature.cluster[0].attributes.tzewn;
                        if (Value < 6)
                            {
                                return "#009cff"; //blue
                            }
                        else if (Value >= 6 && Value < 9)
                            {
                                return "#ec7d3f"; // orange
                            } 
                        else if (Value >= 9 )
                            {
                                return "#ff4a4a"; // red
                            } 
                        else { return "#8a8a8a"; }// grey 
                }
                },
            point_radius: function(feature) {
                if(feature.cluster.length > 1) 
                    return (feature.cluster.length/9) + 12; 
                else  return  12;
            }
```

}}  );

Answer (score 0):

By looking at this example, it does not seem like the markup is used when accessing the property. However, it might be because its defined in the label elsewhere in the same style: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/style-rules.js

so change the line

```
property: "${val}",
```

to

```
property: "val",
```

And see if it works?

Well, to be honest I'm shooting from the hip here. But it might work =)

Comment: No, $ doesn't stand for jQuery in given situation; it's markup for OpenLayers and should be within quatation marks.

Comment: Interesting, I had to look into how that works, I have a new idea that could be tested now then.

Comment: Sorry but property: "val",
doesn't work too.
I have no idea how to transfer average value from cluster to field property: ?

property:"count", from cluster it's o.k.